# what should be the key length in signingCredentials jwt asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

```
public static string GenerateToken(string Username)
{
    var claimsdata = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Username) };
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmqwertlkjfdslkjflksjfklsjfklsjdflskjflyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnmmnbv"));
    var signInCred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha384Signature);
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "mysite",
        audience: "mysite",
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
        claims: claimsdata,
        signingCredentials: signInCred);
    var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    return tokenString;
}
```

//the length of the key is 88 characters. if i reduce it to less than 16 characters it gives an exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'IDX10603: Decryption failed.
>   Keys tried: '[PII is hidden]'. Exceptions caught:  '[PII is hidden]'.
>   token: '[PII is hidden]''

Comment: You may want to read [this article on Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29666), and [this article on Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/95972).

Comment: But I still don't understand why it should be minimum 128 bits.

Answer (score 43):

the minimum length in sha256 in 16 characters because they are 256 hexadecimal bits, then 256/16 = 16

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-hmacsha256-ctor(system-byte())):

[image: HMACSHA256 screenshot of documentation]

So I presume if you use less than this once converted to bytes it should be padded with 0s.

Answer (score 1):

For .NET/.NET Core, the key Secret key should be a minimum of 128 bits i.e (16 bytes)

example:

```
"JwtToken": {
    "SecretKey": "minimumSixteenCharacters",
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:44378"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

32 bytes is enough, see [Key size for HMAC-SHA256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34866).

A 32 bytes array can be expressed as a 64 characters long hexadecimal string, since 2 hexadecimal characters is equal to 1 byte. 32 random bytes, expressed as a hexadecimal string, can be generate with this terminal command:

```bash
$ openssl rand -hex 32
a5e5a0e4bc817ef2774d841c0d300847b3212d96a49a3fe849ecf65d51dadb11
```

To convert a hexadecimal string to a byte array in C#, you may use this extension method:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static byte[] FromHexStringToByteArray(this string hexString) 
    {
        var byteArray = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
        {
            byteArray[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

Then use the extension method to convert the secret key to a byte array, followed by instantiating the `SymmetricSecurityKey` and `SigningCredentials`:

```cs
var secretKey = "a5e5a0e4bc817ef2774d841c0d300847b3212d96a49a3fe849ecf65d51dadb11";
var key = secretKey.FromHexStringToByteArray();
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
```